# ghcid on a single file

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to use `ghcid` on a single file, with a package context provided via the command line, kind of like :

```
 stack runghc --resolver lts-12.20 --package raven-haskell-0.1.2.0 myfile.hs
```

Comment: What happened when you provided that command to the "--command=" parameter?

Comment: `stack runghc --resolver lts-12.20 --package raven-haskell-0.1.2.0 ghcid` yields `target ‘ghcid’ is not a module name or a source file`

Comment: `stack runghc --resolver lts-12.20 --package raven-haskell-0.1.2.0 --command ghcid` yields 
`Invalid option '--command'`

Comment: I guess some sort of `nix-shell` like environment would be the best

Comment: Try `ghcid -o ghcid.txt --command="stack runghc ..."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those command worked with the latest `stack`

- on a plain haskell file

  `ghcid --command "stack repl --resolver lts-12.20 --package raven-haskell-0.1.2.0 --package envy --package servant-server --package warp --package wai --package bytestring using-sentry.hs"`

Note that `raven-haskell-0.1.2.0` is not part of stackage `LTS-12.20`

It simply list every package dependencies and provide a self-contained environment for the haskell file to refer to namespaces contained in them.

- alternatively, a `stack.yaml` describing the extra deps will automatically provide the correct `repl` environment, and obligates the need to list every packages used  : `ghcid --command "stack repl using-sentry.hs"`

Comment: some other ghcid tricks here https://www.parsonsmatt.org/2018/05/19/ghcid_for_the_win.html